# Android Button press strength

Tags: android, touch, screen

Is there an example about how to measure the strength of pressing the screen? I know there is a command, i just cant find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is android.view.MotionEvent.getPressure().

You can also fetch the size of the touch with MotionEvent.getSize().
Beware though, most models have different screens and will behave differently.

EDIT: It also doesn't seem to work with WebView.